# Convert date string to month names in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

The macro searches for a code [DM] and then needs to convert the date found from "17/11/2013" to "17-Nov-2013". I have tried a number of options suggested without any success so far but I expect that I need to sonehow link the cell text as the text to be formatted.

```
Sub ChangeMonth()
Dim strCellText As String

'Change month numbers to words
Do
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[DM]"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    If Selection.Find.Execute = False Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.SelectCell
        Debug.Print Format(CDate(strCellText), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    End If
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: This code can't possible work. You never assign anything to `DateString`, yet you reference it a dozen times on the left side of an equivalence/boolean expression, and although Word is not my specialty, I am certain that VBA does not have a string `.Contains` method.  Also, `Console.WriteLine` doesn't look like VBA to me. Are you sure this is even VBA code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Try simply the `Format` function?

```
Debug.Print Format(#2014/01/01#, "DD/MMM/YYYY")
```

Results in:

```
01/Jan/2014
```

Likewise for other date formats:

```
Debug.Print Format(#01/01/2014#, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
```

Results in:

```
01-Jan-2014
```

The `Format` function takes a date or date-like string as its first argument. Depending on the data you have, you may need to wrap it in `CDate` to ensure the correct conversion, like:

```
Format(Cdate(var), "DD-MM-YYYY")
'assumes "var" is a variable which represents the date/string value
```

[image]

And another screenshot using `CDate` to coerce a string to a date type (although I don't think this is necessary, but just in case):

[image]

In your code I made a few changes:

```
Sub ChangeMonth()
Dim strCellText As String
Dim c As Selection
Dim rng As Range

'Change month numbers to words
Do
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[DM]"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    If Selection.Find.Execute = False Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.SelectCell
        Set c = Selection
        'Set rng = c.Range.Words(1, c.Words.Count - 1)
        strCellText = Trim(Left(c.Text, Len(c.Text) - 2))
        'Debug.Print Format(CDate(strCellText), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
        Selection.Text = Format(CDate(strCellText), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    End If
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: My dates are in the format 01/01/2014 so I tried Debug.Print Format(#01/01/2014", "DD-MMM-YYYY) but the code changes to #1/1/2014# and then doesn't change the format

Comment: See edit above, it looks like you may be doing something wrong.

Comment: How do I get the macro to recognise the cell text as a date to be formatted? I've changed the code to the following:
Sub ChangeMonth()
Dim strCellText As String

Do
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[DM]"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    If Selection.Find.Execute = False Then
        Exit Do
    Else
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.SelectCell
        Debug.Print Format(CDate(strCellText), "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    End If
Loop


End Sub

Comment: please put the code back in the original question (you can revise the Q). It is not easy to read the code in the comments.

Comment: I tried editing it but that doesn't seem to have worked. How do I revise the question? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: no problem. You never assigned any value to the variable `strCellText`

Comment: Your code works wonderfully but I have a further problem. Some date fields are blank and I have tried various options to move forward if the date is blank without success. The lastest option I've tried is "If Not Selection.Text = "" Then" before the Format line but it then says that I have a Loop without Do. What would you do to skip a blank date?